# Tools for identifying near duplicate documents

Tags: nlp

I'm doing a NLP project and identifying near duplicate document is a part of that. Can anyone who has experience with this area suggest the tools (implementations like Weka) available for near duplicate detection?

The project is about generating a statistical report for crimes after analyzing news articles of some local English news papers. The crime articles are firstly classified. Then duplicate articles should be detected and merged. Data collection may contain about 1000 crime related articles for near duplicate detection.

I define near duplicates here as the articles containing the same crime incident. Sometimes different news papers may report the same incidents. Also same news paper may report news articles in different days.

The time taken for duplicate detection is not a problem as this is not online processing. The accuracy is very important here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how big is your collection?

Comment: About 1000 news articles. I updated the question..

Answer (score 3):

Although the notion of `duplicate content` is pretty straightforward, the notion of `near-duplicate content` might be problematic.

For instance, do you consider documents relating to the same event (e.g. news articles from different sources) as NDC?
Or do you consider documents exhibiting the same syntactic patterns (e.g. weather forecasts) as NDC?

Considering your objective, I think you are more interested in the former definition of NDC, however it should be expressed more clearly.

As a first experience you might want to try OnIOn (https://code.google.com/p/onion/) a tool dedicated to DC/NDC detection, but considering the size of your corpus (which is small) you might want to implement your own NDC removal system, based on **your** definition of NDC.
Here I would suggest you to read the seminal paper of Broder *et al.* (http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/SRC-TN-1997-015.pdf)... to give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help... I consider documents relating to the same event as NDC. I will check for the tool and the paper..

Comment: No problem. Please keep in mind that in the case of Broder et al. they had to deal with a huge number of documents, and that their definition for NDC is different than yours. Still it is a must-read when dealing with NDC. Let us know how it went. Good luck.